# Hibernate 5.1 and Java 8 LocalDateTime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, java-8

I've switched to Java 8 and Hibernate 5 to overcome the problem of not being able to store milliseconds in Hibernate.

```
private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

public LocalDateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Maven dependencies

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

Despite this Hibernate is still storing the LocalDateTime object as tinyblob. What am I missing? I'm using MySQL 5.6.19

According to this
[Hibernate Issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844), the hibernate-java8 module should map this to TIMESTAMP. I've tried placing a `@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP)` on the getter, but this led to a DataIntegrityViolationException.

Placed `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")` on the getter. Database table still persisting as tinyblob.

Answer (score 3):

As of this comment:

- Hibernate is at version 5.2.10.Final
- hibernate-java8 is deprecated and all functionality is included in hibernate-core

Hibernate provides type converters for all the JDK date/time types:

- `OffsetDateTime` getters on entities should be annotated with `@Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.OffsetDateTimeType")`
- `LocalDateTime` getters on entities should be annotated with `@Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")`

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql's timestamp does not have millisecond precision so it wouldn't be able to store it as a timestamp, and probably detects this and saves it as a blob.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it stores it as a TINYBLOB is that JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8 and the Date and Time API didn’t exist at that point in time.

To overcome this, you will need to define the mapping to java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp yourself.